# Update permalinks after domain change

Tags: permalinks, urls

I installed my blog in a free hosting webpage, the hosting gave me a free domain and I used that domain in my blog, then I did buy a .net domain, I changed the URL in Settings->General of my dashboard.

I usually edit old posts, the problem is when a reader enters in the blog with the old free domain he gets the old version of my post, when the reader enters with my .net post he gets the modified version

I tried fixing the problem renaming all the link in my database, but it didn't work.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure both the .com and .net domains are pointing at the same server and WordPress installation?

Comment: @EAMann how can I check that? EDIT: I have the .net domain parked on my given free domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option A: [Here’s a Quick Way to Search and Replace Your WordPress Database](http://thewpvalet.com/blog/2012/08/16/heres-a-quick-way-to-search-and-replace-your-database-after-migration/)

Option B: Export your database using phpmyadmin and open in a text editor such as (Notepad++), and use search/replace to find old domain and replace with new domain.
**MAKE SURE YOU BACKUP YOUR DATABASE BEFORE TAKING ANY ACTION**